# Want to transfer information from a listbox that into separate rows in the main table

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a form with a text box (date), combobox (course), combobox (name of attendee).

The name combobox feeds into a list box, so that all the people who attended the course are able to be captured.  The listbox is editable incase the wrong name was selected.

Now I want a button to save all the details.

So for the each person who attended the course, the date, person's name and course name will be captured in a separate line in the table.

But when I try to extract the data from the listbox to the cell it states is a type mismatch.

How can I enter ALL the information into the table?

I have a loop for 0 to listcount

I am entering the value into .Range("A" & Lastrow)...

Currently I have indicated:  Listbox1(x,0).value

I do not know how to extract the Listbox value to the cell.  This doesn't work.  Listbox1(x) doesn't work.  I need every row in the listbox to populate into the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Tammy

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce your issue.  A `Type Mismatch` error occurs when when the wrong data type is supplied and may be a result of an unnoticed spelling error.  Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code module to rule out that possibility.  If you're still stuck then please include all your code.

Comment: Thank you.  That helped.